# saving program state (visual studio 2008)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, savestate

I am debugging (in Visual Studio 2008) a utility I have written in C++. Combining massive input files with my slow machine and it can take upwards of 6 hours to get to the point where I need to watch the program execution for irregularities.

I am probably grasping at straws here, but is anyone aware of feature or plugin or something within Visual Studio or something of the like where I can save program execution state so that I can bypass the time it takes to get where I need to be?

Comment: I hope you heard of [Unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)?

Comment: of course. dealing with self-imposed test cases to test functionality and 1.8 gigs worth of live data are two separate beasts

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure of possibilities within Visual Studio for doing such a thing, but if you can't find anything I would try using a Virtual Machine and saving the state of the machine.
It will probably be horribly slow but may help in the long run.
Good luck

Comment: This idea isn't half-bad, I think it's as close to "saving the program state" as possible.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a `conditional breakpoint`... see this url for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

The idea is that you know what conditions are true for the breakpoint to become valid, then when those conditions are true the breakpoint will trigger, pausing execution. You can then come along in the morning and begin to step through the code.

If you **DO** have an exact point that you want to cause a break at you can put in a programmatic break point DebugBreak() which will cause a break point exception to be thrown. The Visual Studio debugger will catch it and pause execution at that point.

Alternatively, enable `gflags` run the program with `ADPlus` and at the point of the code that you think has caused the problem throw an exception which is not handled. Let the program crash and ADPlus will generate a full crash dump of the process memory. The fact that you had gflags enabled means you will get memory allocations with nice borders around them (`0xCDCDCDCD` usually) for easy debugging.

Finally you can also use the `DbgHelp.dll` [library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679309(v=vs.85).aspx) from Microsoft to generate a mini-dump which can capture various levels of information programmatically (without a crash as the solution above entails). The function you want is **[MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360(v=vs.85).aspx)**. You can write a normal mini-dump or a full memory dump using the parameters. This should be done from a separate process if possible (you can await the handle in your own process).

Comment: thats basically what i'm doing right now. start the execution late at night, check it when i get into the office. start it again, wait and do other things, check again at the end of the day then start it and remote in at home later to check and repeat the process.

Comment: There is the slight downside though that condition breakpoints slow execution down by an order of magnitude, so those 6 hours may become 24.  If you have a particular point in the code that you want to attach to on reaching a condition then I think it's better to put a `while (true) sleep();` type loop in so that you can just break in with the debugger when you get in in the morning

Comment: @basil if you DO have an exact point that you want to cause a break at you can put in a programmatic break point `DebugBreak()` which will cause a break point exception to be thrown. The Visual Studio debugger will catch it and pause execution at that point.

Comment: `DOWNVOTERS` please help me out here. Not sure what I am saying that is causing the downvotes.